# Immutable object with many properties

Tags: php, immutability

I've got a class that I want to make immutable but that class has a lot of properties.

```
<?php

class Gameworld {

    /** @var string */
    private $name;

    /** @var string */
    private $type;

    /** @var bool */
    private $is_online;

    /** @var int */
    private $online_players;

    /** @var int */
    private $online_players_record;

    /** @var string */
    private $description;

    /** @var string */
    private $location;

    /** @var \DateTime */
    private $created_at;

}
```

How to create such object? When I introduce `public function __construct()` with all those properties it will get bloated. If I introduce setters it won't be immutable anymore.

---

**EDIT:** I was thinking about making setters but ones that could be only used once. Thanks to that I won't have bloated constructor but for some reason it seems not like a good idea. Something like:

```
class Gameworld {

    ... old properties ...

    /** @var array */
    private $used_setters = [];

    public function setName(string $name){
        if(in_array('name', $this->used_setters)){
            throw new ImmutableException('Class Gameworld is immutable.');
        }

        $this->name = $name;
        $this->used_setters[] = 'name';
    }

}
```

Comment: Private properties are not immutable. You need constants.

Comment: There's a [RFC for that](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/immutability), but it still under discussion. Look at Money comparison.

Comment: @GabrielHeming I know about that RFC but I'm looking for a solution in current state of things. Still it does not save my problem as I need to create object with all those properties filled, I was thinkig about either making ugly `public function __construct(string $name, string $type, bool $is_online, int $online_players, int $online_players_record, string $description, string $location, \DateTime $created_at)` or Hydrator that would fill those properties using reflection and `setAccessible`.

Comment: There're only two ways to fill immutable objects without creating a new object. Using its `__construct` (that does create an object, but not a new one) or through reflection (there're a lot of libraries to do that). If you use a `set` method (there's no problem) it'll always create a new object and the original object still be immutable. But if you just want to create an object that does not change its properties or even create a new one as time goes on, use constants and block `__clone`. BTW, why does that be immutable? Maybe another approach could solve your problem.

Comment: Should all properties by immutable? or only some? if so, which ones? and what are the possible values?

Comment: @GabrielHeming it is a ValueObject I get from external system through API and it should not change if external system does not change it.

Comment: @WilliamPerron as it is a ValueObject from external system I think all properties should be immutable.

Comment: @simivar then simply use the constructor, tbh 8 properties is really not that much

Comment: @WilliamPerron it's just an example. there's a class with 15 properties etc. It's actually not a solution, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [__set()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) magic method to check if the value is set else I would throw an exception:

```
class Gameworld {

    /** @var string */
    private $name;

    /** @var string */
    private $type;

    /** @var bool */
    private $is_online;

    /** @var int */
    private $online_players;

    /** @var int */
    private $online_players_record;

    /** @var string */
    private $description;

    /** @var string */
    private $location;

    /** @var \DateTime */
    private $created_at;

    public function __set($property, $value)  
    {  
        if (property_exists($this, $property)) {  
            if(is_null($this->$property)){
                $this->$property = $value;
                return $this;
            }
            throw MyCustomException();
        }
        throw UndefinedClassVariableException();
    }
}
```

A basic usage would be:

```
$x = new Gameworld();
$x->name = "OK";
$x->is_online = true;
$x->name="Exception";
```

**P.S**: Exceptions must [extend the base exception class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php) or you could [trigger](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) or [log](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) an error, depends on what you want

**P.S.S**: An alternative sollution would be to use [__call()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) method and check if the value is null

Comment: So it's similar to my propsition from edit. I see two faults with this solution: first is that it does not ensures integrity of data and second is that a value actually can be `null` from beggining.

Comment: @simivar so maybe keep private array of actually setted properties and instead of "is_null" use "in_array($this->userProps)" ?

Comment: Data integrity should be done before retrieval or on persistance (single point of truth). They can be null indeed, you either set them all at once or one by one ( I would recommend a factory design pattern to ensure all properties are set)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest passing properties as an array argument like

```
__construct( array $properties )
{
  $this->property = $properties['property'];
  ....
}
```

Comment: It seems like best approach for now but sad thing is that I won't be able to ensure that every property has valid type (string, int etc.).

Comment: Might be overkill but you could have a `GamewordProperties` class which ensures the integrity of the properties then `__construct(GamewordProperties $properties) { ... }`

Comment: @CD001 I'm torn about this solutions. Seems great but still I'm making second class that is almost the same as the main one.